# Contour integration with a complex variable

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Attempting an old problem sheet question:

> Use the Cauchy integral formula to compute (for any $a \in \mathbb{C}$),
>   $$ \int_{|z|=1} \frac{\exp{az}}{2z^2 - 5z+ 2} dz $$

By following the example on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Example) I arrive at

$$ \int_{|z|=1} \frac{\exp{az}}{2z^2 - 5z+ 2} dz = \frac{4 \pi i\exp{(\frac{1}{2} a)}}{3} $$

But nowhere did I have any consideration for what $a \in \mathbb{C}$ is. My thought is that it doesn't affect anything, since it doesn't change where the poles of $\frac{\exp{az}}{2z^2 - 5z+ 2}$ lie, but is this easily shown? And if it *does* affect it, how do we work out what affect it has (is it a pre- or post- integrating problem)?

Comment: I think you want to integrate over the circle $|z|=1$. $B(0,1)$ is usually used for the entire disk $|z|<1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes that's what I meant, thanks, I've edited it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $f$ has   a simple pole at a point $c$ the residue is given by $\lim_{z \to c} f(z)$. The poles in this case are at 2 and 1/2 and only 1/2 is inside the circle.. To find the residue at 1/2 use continuity of the exponential function: $\lim_{z \to 1/2} (z-1/2) \frac {e^{az}} {2z^{2}-5z+2}=e^{(1/2)a}\lim_{z \to 1/2} (z-1/2) \frac {e^{az}} {2z^{2}-5z+2}$ which you can compute by factoring the denominator.

Comment: Doing this I get calculate the residue to be $\frac{2 \exp{a}}{3}$, and then using the Cauchy integral formula this gives the desired integral to be $\frac{4 \pi i \exp{a}}{3}$ I think? Is this then valid for whatever $a \in \mathbb{C}$ we choose?

Comment: It is, $a$ doesn't affect the position nor the nature of the poles since $\exp(az)$ is holomorphic for all $a\in \mathbb{C}$